# How to use appname://open to launch desired application from web browser in Windows OS?

Tags: laravel

I discovered this URL while working with Laravel (just getting started).

I've done some research on this but everything I find in StackExchange are StackOverflow topics. I think this is more of an O/S topic, but being unfamiliar w/ this syntax I'm not sure where to inquire.

I think it's specific to Ignition ( https://flareapp.io/ignition ), but they seem to want you to pay for that? What?

I've been a Linux user for nearly 20 years, but I don't recall ever this type of URL to open apps from a web browser.

By default, the URL linked in the Laravel error page is e.g. phpstorm://open?file=C%3A%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Cblahblahblah

I don't have PHPStorm. I just want it to open in VSCode. I'm going down a rabbit hole. It's not THAT important, but someone here knows what i'm talking about. I don't want Mac iOS / Linux instructions. This should be quite easy to answer. Thank you.

I have tried searching docs at https://flareapp.io/ but I can't find the answer, and it is a paid service. I expect to be able to assign an application to a configuration file such that clicking the "link" in the Laravel error page http://flareapp.io/docs/ignition-for-laravel/introduction would open VS Code, as is proclaimed.

Comment: You can change your preferred editor via the cog/config icon in the top right of the error page. I'm not running Windows so I can't confirm how the the `phpstorm://` or `vscode://` links work in Windows. The [Ignition](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-ignition) error page is completely free to use standalone, but the optional Flare service is there if you'd like the addition features.

Comment: @KirkBeard - thank you for this info. I don't think I have a cog/config icon in the top right of the error page. https://i.imgur.com/ciyndJO 
Hovering the "Pencil" icon however is where i see the hyperlink "phpstorm://open?file=". While the screenshot is not the complete page, there's nothing else on it that i found that seems to be a cog, or otherwise linking to config settings. I've no doubt i'm missing something, but maybe this isn't the same type of error page you're referencing?

Thank you!

Comment: @KirkBeard - i was short of time when i initially posted. a quick GREP search shows the following in file `..\vendor\facade\ignition\config\ignition.php:17`
`'editor' => env('IGNITION_EDITOR', 'phpstorm'),` 
which probably corresponds with `/* PrettyPageHandler.php */ class PrettyPageHandler extends Handler [~snip~] public function setEditor($editor)` i'm not on that project currently, but i'll post if i investigate this further and achieve what i was looking for. Ignition.js contains: `o={sublime:"subl://open?url=file://%path&line=%line", 
[~SNIP~] vscode:"vscode://file/%path:%line",...};`